# Unable to see the label in the view Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, remenu

I have a view controller called "Help". I placed a label on the view controller story board, but in simulation I couldn't see the label. I used `REMenu` to put a menu at the top of the view. I can see the menu bar, but I cannot see the label. Here are the files.

```
#import "Help.h"

@interface Help ()

@end

@implementation Help
@synthesize helpText1;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =

    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(handleBack:)];
    helpText1.text=@"Hiii";
    helpText1.hidden=NO;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)handleBack:(id)otherView{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *myVC = (Controller *)[storyboard            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QRList"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is the code that calls the "Help" view controller.When we click on the help option in the menu, it will call the "help" view controller.

```
REMenuItem *helpItem = [[REMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Help"
                                                subtitle:nil
                                                   image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ic"]
                                        highlightedImage:nil
                                                  action:^(REMenuItem *item) {
                                                      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                                                      Help *controller = [[Help alloc] init];
                                                      [weakSelf setViewControllers:@[controller] animated:NO];
                                                  }];
```

The "Help" view controller is getting called but I couldn't see the label which I dragged on storyboard. I couldn't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that your label is being at a wrong view. Probably, your pushed controller doesn't contain the label you put in your nib file. Try to add other objects and see what's happening. If the problem is that I just guessed, then find the exact controller, choose a view and put there the label. Hope you solve that!

Comment: Yes you are right....I used storyboard Id to push the right controller and now it works fine.                                                    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                                                                      @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                                          Help *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Help"];

Answer (score 0):

Use debug, put breakpoints, to see where you lose label. Check your layouts, maybe...tie your lable to **top Space to superView**, **leading or tralling space to supeView** or **bottom space to superView**. And beginning Xcode 4.4 we don't need **synthesize**, each added default